# Nucleo-STM32F401RE + ST-Link problem - cannot connect to the target

Tags: stm32, st-link

I have a problem with the connection. Yesterday my board stopped working (there is a file FAIL.txt: "The interface firmware FAILED to reset/halt the target MC" at board disk).
I've done some research on how to fix it, but neither pressing reset nor connecting boot0 to Vdd worked. After some time I managed to connect to the board - I removed JP5 jumper and connected MCU to STLINK (on the same board) through wires ([How to reconnect nucleo to st-link part?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/167414/how-to-reconnect-nucleo-to-st-link-part?fbclid=IwAR12UtXxHSWWmmkMm0jdQfsTs6W7m9ceGbmUm2YVHVktu4JB0TC_ARUsv9I)) and after many tries to unplug and plug the USB cable sometimes it works - I can programm my board as before.
Any ideas on what could it be and how to fix it?
EDIT: Ok, it's not stlink. So when Im taking off PWR jumper and inserting it again couple (random number) times it finally connects and then I can work normally until I reconnect cable. Any idea?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.